# How to make a virtual field function use the same Ellipsoid settings as the normal field calculator?

Tags: qgis

I have a new shapefile layer in CRS 3857, in a project that has the same CRS.
Under project properties, the measure tool is on ellipsoid WGS 84.

When i use the field calculator to create a new field for the layer and use the function "$area", the fields get filled with the correct values.

Now when i use the field calculator to add a **virtual field** with the function "$area", the values in the field represent the area value of the features calculated **without ellipsoid** (None/Planimetric).

Is there a way to make the virtual field function use the same Ellipsoid setting as the normal field calculator?

Comment: For as far as i can read on the forums and already posted questions, it seems like this is a bug in QGIS (i'm using 2.8.1). I reported an issue on it here : https://hub.qgis.org/issues/12622
Not sure if there is a solution currently available.